# how to make emulator running prossesor AMD

Tags: android-emulator, emulation, amd-processor

I am getting the following error when running the `emulator` like this:

```
emulator: ERROR: x86 emulation currently requires hardware acceleration!
Please Ensure Intel HAXM is properly installed and usable.
CPU acceleration status: HAX kernel module is not installed!
```

And here I use `AMD` processors, is there any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

Intel HAXM only runs on certain Intel processors that support Virtualization and ND bit. There are other alternative emulators to the built in one - like GenyMotion

Comment: is there any example for combining genymotion in the studio or tutorials android ..?